# Float left div not taking up all the width

Tags: html, css

I have the following snippet where i want the side-text div to be placed on the right side of the image, but unless i specify the with of this side-text div, it will automatically move to the bottom (as it is now)

I have tried displaying the elements with `display:inline-block` but then the side-text div gets aligned to the bottom of the image.

https://jsfiddle.net/f0jheskv/

```css
.content {
  width: 800px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.text {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: rgb(150, 150, 150)
}
.code {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: rgb(200, 200, 200)
}
.side-text {
  background-color: rgb(200, 100, 100)
}
.img-strip {
  width: 100%
}
.img-strip img,
.img-strip div {
  float: left
}
.clear {
  clear: both
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <h3>
  Title
  </h3>

  <div class="text">
    Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500, cuando un impresor (N. del T. persona que se dedica a la imprenta) desconocido usó
    una galería de textos y los mezcló de tal manera que logró hacer un libro de textos especimen.
  </div>

  <div class="img-strip">
    <img width="320px" height="240px" />
    <div class="side-text">Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500, cuando un impresor (N. del T. persona que se dedica a la imprenta) desconocido
      usó una galería de textos y los mezcló de tal manera que logró hacer un libro de textos especimen.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>

  <div class="code">
    <pre>
  for(int i=0; i<9; i++){
    a=0;
    b=3;
  }
    </pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Float just the image, not `.img-strip div` and remove the `display: inline-block;` from `.side-text`:

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/f0jheskv/2/)**

Or use `display: table-cell` to position them:

```
.img-strip img,
.img-strip div {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.img-strip {
  display: table;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/f0jheskv/4/)**

Comment: Its on top of the image

Comment: Um, no it's not. Are you referring to the fiddle? There's no image in it (using your code). Here's the same fiddle with a placeholder image https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/f0jheskv/3/

Comment: sorry its not on top, its below, if ur browser is slow enough u will see the red background spanning all the way below the placeholder image, before the image is then displayed on top. If u dont use a placeholder image then u see clearly how it spans accross the area where the image goes.

Comment: Yes, it does run below, that's what floating the image does. If you feel that a flash of color under an image that hasn't loaded yet is an issue, you could alternately use `display:table-cell` to position the elements as you want. See https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/f0jheskv/4/

Comment: Well its not just the flash, its also that then if i want an empty gap between divs it wont be possible anymore. Thanks for the tip on `display:table-cell` didn't know that either : (

Comment: ALthough both answers are working well, i am going to use your last suggestion with `display:table-cell` because i feel it is the most simple i.e. no need to float elements etc. Can you update the answer so that i can accept it?

Answer (score 2):

You can set your div to the desired width and then use `display:flex;` on the `.img-strip` container. This way, the div height is enlarged to the images height. [Here is a great tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) about the flex property.

```css
.content {
  width: 800px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.text {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: rgb(150, 150, 150);
}
.code {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
}
.side-text {
  background-color: rgb(200, 100, 100);
  float: right;
  flex: 1;
}
.img-strip {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}
.img-strip img {
  float: left;
}
.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <h3>
  Title
  </h3>

  <div class="text">
    Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500, cuando un impresor (N. del T. persona que se dedica a la imprenta) desconocido usó
    una galería de textos y los mezcló de tal manera que logró hacer un libro de textos especimen.
  </div>

  <div class="img-strip">
    <img width="320px" height="240px" />
    <div class="side-text">Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500, cuando un impresor (N. del T. persona que se dedica a la imprenta) desconocido
      usó una galería de textos y los mezcló de tal manera que logró hacer un libro de textos especimen.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>

  <div class="code">
    <pre>
  for(int i=0; i<9; i++){
    a=0;
    b=3;
  }
    </pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The size of the image gets distorted... using `dispaly:flex` for the img-strip element, is that normal?

Comment: ok now after ur edit its working well, thanks! I had never seen `display:flex` before, is it a new html5 thing?

Comment: It's CSS3 and a very good way to build flexible layouts! Updated my anser with a link to a good tutorial.

Comment: You are fixing the width of the side-text div, that wont be possible when the size of the image is unknown...

Comment: Ah sorry, that's not necessary, I removed it. (I tried a little bit with the sizing before...)